# The modifier 'new' is not valid for this item

Tags: c#

I created a class `GroupPrincipalExtension : GroupPrincipal` as you can see it inherits from  `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal`

Now when I try to create a constructor in my extension class,

```
public new GroupPrincipalExtension()
{
    //do something
}
```

I get this error,

> The modifier 'new' is not valid for this item

Based on what I read, we can add own constructors to derived class with or without 'new' keyword

**Edit**

If i remove new keyword:

> 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' does not
>   contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Answer (score 3):

Remove `new` from the constructor and it should work. You only declare the `new` keyword when you're creating an instance.

Also since it inherits from another class you might want to declare it like this:

```
public GroupPrincipalExtension()
    : base() // Parameters ??
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: [or hiding a base method in a derived class.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: or to restrict types that might be used as arguments for a type parameter in a generic declaration

Comment: None of that is related to constructors, so why bring it up?

Comment: Because you say: *"You only declare the new keyword when you're creating an instance."*, which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 3):

[`GroupPrincipal` doesn't have a default constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350614(v=vs.110).aspx). It's slimiest constructor is one which takes a [`PrincipalContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext(v=vs.110).aspx), which is exactly what you need to take as an argument in your constructor:

```
public GroupPrincipalExtension(PrincipalContext context) : base(context)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: so does that means, derived classes can't have constructors with 0 arguments :S ?

Comment: they can, but you would need to pass in the argument to the base class constructor ie `: base(object)` etc

Comment: You could still have an empty constructor, but you'd need to generate the `PrincipalContext` and pass it down to the `base` somehow.